# Spam daily report on servers using sendmail

Tags: spam, sendmail, procmail

we'd like to implement a daily spam report to our users like Dreamhost does.
Basically we need to send a daily mail (at midnight for example) to inform a single user of all the emails currently in his spam folder with the related score to let them look right away if there's a false positive.
We use a basic sendmail server with procmail to redirect spam to the spam folder in each home directory.

Do you know if is there a perl script or some other tool that does just that?

Thank you very much

Comment: Was my answer in any way helpful?

Answer (score 1):

It's highly likely Dreamhost is using a home-grown script and that is likely what you will have to do as well.  You should be able to do it without too much fuss in bash or perl.

Comment: Thank you, yes it shouldn't be any difficult if I could manage to have an internal good with bash or perl. Unfortunately any of us isn't so I was looking for a ready-made script. I wonder why there's not so much around since I think this is a killer feature to add to a simple hosting / mail service.
Modules like webmin can fetch with no problem local mbox files, I should manage to hack a script to do just what I want. 
Thank you for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact solution to your problem, but [this](http://www.cs.chalmers.se/~tveldhui/tools/spam/) is pretty similar and should help you getting what you want. Else search on Google for "daily spam digest". This should give you some more useful results.